# Recommendation on how to store mp3 and image files in Core Data which is synced with CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsdata, cloudkit

I have an app that needs to work offline but sync across devices. The plan is to use Core Data and CloudKit to achieve this.

My question is how to store mp3 and image files (small file sizes). Is it ok to store it as Data and enable "Allows external storage" ? Will That works for CloudKit synchronisation

Comment: short answer is "enable external storage" can sync with CloutKit, as Blob is simply mirrored to an CKAsset. <https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/reading_cloudkit_records_for_core_data>

Comment: Although, Core Data managed Blob is opaque, and Core Data with CloudKit sync is even more opaque. To manage large Blob like mp3 or image yourself, is always advisable but you'd have to deal with all the distributed-system complexities.